# Communication between AWS VPC instances via public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-vpc

We have two AWS instances (Instance A and Instance B) which are running in the same VPC. There is an internet facing service on Instance A which is restricted (via security group) to a subset of IP addresses.  Instance A has a DNS entry so the service can be accessed via someservice.example.org.

When trying to access the service from Instance B it works correctly if we used the VPC internal IP address however we cannot seem to get the correct security group configuration to allow this instance access via the public DNS.

We have added the 'default' VPC security group to Instance A but we're still unable to access this service directly.  We also have the same problem trying to configure access to Instance A from other VPCs.

I know that we can create a private DNS for the VPC which could solve the problem when we are in the same VPC but this doesn't get around the problem when running in another VPC.

Comment: You do understand that you have to configure the security group to allow access from the client instance'a public IP address or the address of the NAT instance that the client instance's subnet uses, if the client instance doesn't have a public IP, right?  You can't allow access into an instance's public IP by specifying a private address block or sg-xxxxxxxx in the security group settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a DNS resolution issue. If you are using Route53 for DNS the easiest way to fix this is to create a private Route53 DNS zone for your VPC and add something like:
CNAME 'someservice.example.org' that points to the instance's internal IP address.

Note that you really want to use the internal private IP address whenever possible. It will keep the network traffic within your VPC, which will be much faster and more secure. It may also be cheaper for you, at least if the instances are also within the same availability zone. You can read more about that on the [EC2 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) in the Data Transfer section.

Also note that you can't open up the security group to allow only instances from your VPC/security group to access something via the public IP. This is because the traffic hitting the public IP is seen as coming "from the internet", not from your VPC. You would have to grant access to the servers via their public IP addresses instead of their security groups.

You mention also using a second VPC, but that would be a separate problem that could be addressed via [VPC Peering](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html).

Comment: This is as I suspected. Will definitely be going down the private DNS zone route. Hadn't considered the cost implications of public-to-public IP connections. Thanks.